# Reload full page with JS with all script calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Good day.
So what Im trying to do is fully reload page with AJAX(I really need to put overlay that say "Loading..." on top of page while reloading it, so JS is the only way).

Load works fine:

```
jQuery('body').load(document.URL,function(){
     //some random stuff here
})
```

But the biggest problem is that i have a lot of js in head-tag so it breaks completely after load. Is there any way to fully reload page with "Loading" overlay in process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't put 'A LOT OF JS' in your head tag. This is not a good practice. Anyway you need to post here the relevant code because in this way you will not able to get any help.